# awk + print line only if the first field start with string as Linux1

Tags: text-processing, awk

how to print the line in case the first field start with Linux1

for example:

```
  echo Linux1_ver2  12542 kernel-update  |   awk '{if ($1 ~ Linux1 ) print $0;}'
```

the target is to print the line , while the first field start with Linux1

example of lines:

```
Linux1-new  36352 Version:true
Linux1-1625543  9847
Linux1:16254 8467563
```

remark  - space or TAB could be before the first filed

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One way:

```
echo "Linux1_ver2  12542 kernel-update"  |  awk '$1 ~ /^ *Linux1/'
```

Comment: $1 and ^ are redundant. Your proposal doesn't cover tabs.

Comment: @HuakeLaging Why do you think the $1 and ^ are redundant? I am quite sure both are required so that the first word is matched against only, and so that the match is anchored at the start (e.g., "mLinux" could be matched by /Linux1/, but not by /^Linux/).

Answer (score 45):

awk ignores leading blanks when assigning fields.  The default command is print.

```
awk '$1 ~ /^Linux1/'
```

Is what you want.

Detailed explanation:

- $1 tells awk to look at the first "column".
- ~ tells awk to do a RegularExpression match /..../ is a Regular expression.
- Within the RE is the string Linux and the special character ^.
- ^ causes the RE to match from the start (as opposed to matching anywhere in the line).

Seen together: Awk will match a regular expression with "Linux" at the start of the first column.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for this specific case.

```
awk '/^[[:blank:]]*Linux1/ {print}'
```

Comment: but if space is before Linux1 the it will no match

Comment: @yael I made an edit to correct that.

Comment: +1 To anyone wondering what this syntax is doing: it's saying "do the things inside the braces only if the regex matches that line".